# Perl Catalyst - Prevent double path in url eg. http://mydomainname/login/login

Tags: html, css, perl, model-view-controller, catalyst

I am creating a Catalyst application, currently I have a simple login page that I access by going to the url:

```
http://mydomainname/login
```

This works perfectly, it fetches the html page and using the css file it references creates a pretty login page.

However, If I also go to the following url:

```
http://mydomainname/login/login
```

**The login page I created still gets displayed, except this time it just displays the basic buttons, textboxes and so on without the css, as it appears it is not accessing the css file for styling.**

This happens all the time 'login' is in the path:

eg.

```
http://mydomainname/login/login
http://mydomainname/login/login/login
http://mydomainname/login/login/login/login/login
```

and so on...

What I want is obviously for `http://mydomainname/login/login` not to work or redirect to just `http://mydomainname/login` for example.

**Im my Login.pm Controller I have:**

```
sub default : Private {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->forward('login');  
}

sub login : Path('/login') {  
        my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

        $c->stash->{title} = 'Login Page';
        $c->stash->{pagetype} = "html";
        $c->stash->{template} = "login.html";
}
```

Firstly, is this how the controller should look? **and what do I need to do to prevent this double url path problem from occurring** (eg `http://mydomainname/login/login` or `http://mydomainname/login/login/login/login`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `/login` is being matched from the Controller name, and the second `/login` is being matched from the Action name (the sub).

You either need to move the entire `login` sub into your Root controller, or move its logic into the existing `default` handler. Personally, I prefer to put actions like login and logout into the Root controller. They're unlikely to have anything else chained to them or dependent on them. Does Login.pm have any other actions or methods?

The missing CSS styling is likely to be an issue of relative paths in your login.html, or the configuration of static resources in your main program. You should be able to debug that one with your browser's Dev Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly say that there should be no arguments:

```
sub login :Path('/login') :Args(0) {
```

Then the controller won't match `/login/etc/etc/etc`

Comment: Even when I add this, going to `http://mydomainname/login/etc/etc` will still display the 'Login' page, except minus the css styling? Is there anything else it could be or do I need to do something else? thanks for your help